# A free Step by Step guide to learning Sparx Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have just downloaded Sparx Enterprise Architect 7.5 but unfortunately I am not able to find a getting started guide or something like that.

I have gone through official site of Sparx but there is not step by step guide to learning Sparx EA.

I want a guide that will implement a small project and give instructions step by step so that I can understand and try out Sparx EA.

I did find a few sites selling step by step guides but at this point of time I do not want to spend money on them.

Comment: see my answer under http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388309/sparx-system-enterprise-architect-book

Comment: The first things that were confusing to me: *Model: Each root node of the project is a model element.
*Package: A grouping element that contains other elements(including other packages) and diagrams.
*View: A top level package element. I learned these through the online docs pages such as this:https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/15.1/modeling_tools/packagetasks.html, this:https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/15.1/modeling/manageviews.html  and this:https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/15.1/model_navigation/viewcontextmenu.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should see Getting Started docked on the left in EA

[alt text http://www.cmsjr.com/img/eaGettingStarted.jpg](http://www.cmsjr.com/img/eaGettingStarted.jpg)

Comment: Thanks, I missed the Getting Started docked on right in my case.

Comment: I tried this link today and got a `404 not found` error and the base URL [www.cmsjr.com](http://www.cmsjr.com) looks like a stub that hasn't been updated in 7 years, so I think this link is dead.

Answer (score 5):

See also [Enterprise Architect Product Demonstrations](http://sparxsystems.com/resources/demos/index.html) and the [UML Tutorials](http://www.sparxsystems.com/uml-tutorial.html).

Keep in mind, this is a UML tool. It's possible that part of what you need is a step by step guide to understanding UML. If these tutorials don't help you, I suggest [UML Distilled: A Brief Guide to the Standard Object Modeling Language (3rd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321193687) by Martin Fowler. Before reading this book, I felt that UML was this huge, tangled ball of twine. This book showed me the starting point, from which I was able to unravel the ball of twine.