# Sparx System Enterprise Architect Book

Tags: enterprise-architect

Does anyone know if there is a book about Sparx systems Enterprise Architect ? (besides sparx site and reference)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sparxsystems Central Europe offer their own book, based on Enterprise Archtect.
Project Management with UML and Enterprise Architect
ISBN-10:3-9502692-1-5
ISBN-13:978-3-9502692-1-5
An adoption to EA 8.0is is in work and will released end of Aug. 2010.
Further Info http://www.sparxsystems.eu/ea-sparx-systems/ea-news/news-beitrag/article/new-book-released-project-management-with-uml-and-enterprise-architect/

Comment: As of 2020, this link is dead.

Answer (score 7):

There is a good book with a practical example.

"Use case Driven Object Modeling with UML" written by Doug Rosenberg and Matt Stephens

They explain there methode how to develop with the relevant parts of UML. They refer a lot to the Sparx Enterprise Architect tool.

Comment: I got the book from apress as well as pdf

Answer (score 3):

There is also a digital version of the book mentioned above: you can find it at http://leanpub.com/entarch

Advantages of the ebook:

- available in pdf, epub (for iPad, iPhone, eReaders) and mobi (for Amazon Kindle)
- cheaper
- includes a bonus chapter
- free updates
- immediate download

Answer (score 1):

Peter Doomen has recently released an e-Book (pdf, ePub, Mobi-Kindle) version of Fifty Enterprise Architect Tricks. Also available in paperback which I've read and enjoyed. Find it at https://leanpub.com/entarch

Comment: I'm afraid your link is broken. Fortunately, Peter posted a working link to the same book a little after yours https://leanpub.com/entarch